# How can I access variables stored in the dynamic memory in a different function?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, heap-memory, clion

So I made this little piece of code that asks the user the size of an array and the contents of the array (in order) and makes the array in the dynamic memory (heap?).

```
void leesgetallen() {
    int *n = new int();
    cout << " Wat is de lengte van de Array?" << endl;
    cin >> *n;
    int g;
    int *A = new int[*n];
    cout << "Geef de getallen van de Array in stijgende volgorde." << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < *n; i++) {
        cout << "Geef getal nummer " << i << " :";
        cin >> g;
        A[i] = g;
    }
    cout << "Ter controle, dit is de ingegeven Array: ";
    for (int *pa = A; pa != A + *n; pa++) {
        cout << *pa << " ";
    }
}
```

On its own this works perfectly.

However when I then try to use this array (A) and size of said array (*n), it doesn't recognize A and *n. I don't quite understand how I can use these variables as to my understanding if they are in the dynamic memory they should be global?

The reason I need to access them is because I want to use a different function to calculate the average of an inputted array.

like so.

```
int gem(int a[], int n) {
    int som = 0;
    for (int *pa = a; pa != a + n; pa++) {
        som += *pa;
    }
    int gemiddelde = som / n;
    cout << "Het gemiddelde van deze array is: " << gemiddelde << endl;
    return gemiddelde;
}


void leesgetallen() {
    int *n = new int();
    cout << " Wat is de lengte van de Array?" << endl;
    cin >> *n;
    int g;
    int *A = new int[*n];
    cout << "Geef de getallen van de Array in stijgende volgorde." << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < *n; i++) {
        cout << "Geef getal nummer " << i << " :";
        cin >> g;
        A[i] = g;
    }
    cout << "Ter controle, dit is de ingegeven Array: ";
    for (int *pa = A; pa != A + *n; pa++) {
        cout << *pa << " ";
    }
}


int main() {
    leesgetallen();
    gem(A, *n);
    delete *n;
    delete[] A;
}
```

Can anyone help me out?

ps: all text is in dutch, but that shouldn't really matter I hope.

Comment: the problem is not the dynamic variables: it's the pointer variables `A` and `n`, which are not dynamic. If you only wanted to get one value out of a function, you could use a `return` statement.  To get more than one value out, you have to use pointer parameters, e.g. `void leesgetallen(int **placeWhereTheCallerWantUsToPutA, int *placeWhereTheCallerWantsUsToPutN)` and `int *mainA; int mainN; leesgestallen(&mainA, &mainN);`

Comment: You use values from one function in another function by returning those values from the first function. This is true of pointers to dynamic memory (like you have) and everything else. Dynamic memory affects the *lifetime* of an object (how long it lives) not the *scope* of a object (where in the program it can be seen).

Comment: *in dynamic memory so they should be global*. This is wrong.

Comment: @user253751 I am indeed trying to get 2 values out of one function however I don't quite understand what you did with your pointer parameters and how exactly they work. With your solution I am still not able to then use those parameters in another function.

Comment: @Yunnerd I think if you search for how to return two things from a function you will find some ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new int[*n]` creates new, global (in a sense), unnamed array, and returns pointer to its beginning. That pointer is the only way to access that array. But `A`, the variable you store it in, is local to `leesgetallen` so can only be accessed from said function. To overcome that, you can define `A` and `n` in `main`, for example, and pass references (or pointers) to these variables into `leesgetallen`. (Or, as @lorro suggested, return their values in a tuple)

Also note that `n` doesn’t need dynamic allocation as you know for sure it will be exactly one `int` for your whole program.

Answer (score 0):

Main ways of communicating something from within a function to caller / external:

- `return` the variable. That's what functions are about, anyways. You might return multiple variables using either a `std::tuple<>`, or simply declare a struct for the return type (preferred for complex types).
- Make it a member function and update the object it's applied to.
- Use an output argument (e.g. an `int*& A`). This is usually less preferred over returning the variable; in the past, it was very common to return e.g. status code this way.
- Update a global variable (usually `static` variable)
- Call a function that processes the result. This might just update a global, or do something else. The processing function is either known in your function, or is passed to it as a template (or in some cases, function pointer / `std::function<>`) argument. Template argument has the benefit that you don't need to know the type in advance (e.g. `int` or `long`). It's common to implement factories this way. When it's the last call in your function, it's called continuation passing.
- Update the environment (e.g. a file, or other externals). This is especially useful in large systems where there might be multiple instances of your code working together, but is also orders of magnitude slower (for your actual thread) than the other methods.

Note that variables won't be globally visible just because they're dynamically allocated. You still need to choose a way to have them visible for the caller (or other part of the code where you'd use them).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I found the solution. And understand a lot more about dynamic allocation and memory management.

Here is the solution for future reference.

```
int gem(int a[], int n) {
    int som = 0;
    for (int *pa = a; pa != a + n; pa++) {
        som += *pa;
    }
    int gemiddelde = som / n;
    cout << "Het gemiddelde van deze array is: " << gemiddelde << endl;
    return gemiddelde;
}


void leesgetallen(int *n, int *A) {
    cout << " Wat is de lengte van de Array?" << endl;
    cin >> *n;
    int cn = *n;
    cout << "controle: n = " << *n << endl;
    int g = 0;
    cout << "Geef de getallen van de Array in stijgende volgorde." << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i != cn; i++) {
        cout << "Geef getal nummer " << i + 1 << " :";
        cin >> g;
        A[i] = g;
    }
    cout << "Ter controle, dit is de ingegeven Array: " << endl;
    for (int *pa = A; pa != A + *n; pa++) {
        cout << *pa << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}


int main() {
    int n = 0;
    int *A = new int[n];
    leesgetallen(&n, A);
    gem(A, n);
    delete[] A;
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. At the moment you call `new int[n];`, `n` is still zero so zero-length array is created. The program may seem to work, until you test it on larger data.

Comment: I suggest passing `A` by pointer too, like `leesgetallen(int *n, int **A)` and  `leesgetallen(&n, &A)`,  and allocating the array in `leesgetallen`. Yes, you can have a pointer to a pointer. You may need a bit weird syntax like `(*A)[i]`, though.

Comment: Also, use `valgrind` or a similar tool (address sanitizer?), they are good at catching incorrect memory access (e.g. out of bounds as in your example)